# Connecting external database from Cassandra cluster hosted in GCP?

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I have set up a single node datastax Cassandra cluster in  Google cloud. Can someone now help me how to connect to an external teradata database which is installed locally in a VM?

what are steps I need to follow?

Comment: You wouldn't connect one DB straight to another, you'd likely be running an application or script to connect to both and then move, copy etc the data from one to the other. Could you please add a bit more detail here on things like; Cassandra verison, driver vesion, where the app / script is running, where the Teradata DB is you say "local VM" are you behind a NAT gatweway etc?

Comment: Do you want to copy the data from local VM to cluster in GCP or you want to connect to the local VM data in GCP cluster?

Comment: @markc ..Thanks a lot for taking out time to reply. I have just set up a datastax cluster in GCP. I have not installed any driver in the cluster .Actaullay that's the whole point..I am not getting information how to install any driver if needed to copy data form my local VM teradata insatnce. I think I am using a bridged network in my local VM player settings.

Comment: @JinnaBalu..Thanks a lot for taking out time to reply..I want to copy the data from local VM to cluster in GCP . Bluk import you can say

Comment: @Aniruddhya Dutta - right so you still need to ETL (Extract transform load) here. First half of this is connecting the two instances; You'll need to ensure you have a network route between the two. Second half is what you can use to transfer the data and how to set it up. Please provide a bit more detail in your original question, Casandra version, where you are running the ETL from, where your Teradata is located, any network topology etc.

Comment: @markc..thanks a lot for the inputs..i will share the details..but can u have a look here if u havn't alreday..https://www.datastax.com/2012/03/how-to-move-data-from-relational-databases-to-datastax-enterprise-cassandra-using-sqoop